# How to cast a youtube video from ios using the iFrame API?

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

I want to cast a youtube video through my ios device to chromecast. I started by using Google's CastHelloText-ios sample application on github. However, I am having a lot of trouble finding the right documentation for this task.

Does anyone know how I can get started?

EDIT:

I've created some HTML/javascript code to handle the youtube iFrame api stuff. Using the HelloText sender app, I pass in a url to my HTML code. However I noticed that the youtube video starts to play for a while but immediately stops after a few seconds.

Comment: i need to implement this on my app, could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Does anyone know how I can get started
?**

You can get started by checking out [Integrate Cast v3 into your iOS App](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_integrate) since you're using iOS.

The guide recommends that you try:

> Cast [iOS codelab
>   tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/tutorials) - Learn
>   step-by-step how to enable an existing iOS video app to use a Google
>   Cast device to cast videos to a TV.
>
> [CastVideos-ios sample
>   app](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios) (GitHub) - Run,
>   navigate and view this reference sample app which complies with the UX
>   Guidelines and Design Checklist.

Not sure if it will help but you may also checkout [Embed YouTube Videos in iOS Applications with the YouTube Helper Library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper)

Comment: enjoy the bounty reward